# Joint Probability: How do I find the proportion of incidents when specified criteria are met?

Tags: r, osx-mavericks

I have data sets that include soil temperatures and soil moisture content for individual days of the year. I want to find the proportion of days when both variables pass certain threshold values needed for seed germination (i.e. the answer i need will be something like in X % of  days the soil and moisture meet the specified criteria simultaneously).

After reading over stackoverflow I was thinking that the mvtnorm package might do what I need but I can't get it to produce the output I need. I use R a lot for data exploration and analysis but my actual scripting/coding ability is very poor. I take worked examples and adapte them to my needs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to attach example data but couldn't make it work. Basically its just two columns of data, both numeric.

```
SoilTemps,  SoilMoist
18.1,   -150303.4661
18.16283368,    -150303.4661
18.21250712,    -150303.4661
18.56594505,    -150303.4662
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions available. Here is one option that should get you started.

```
# Assume the data is as below
DF <- structure(list(x = c(18.1, 18.16283, 18.21251, 18.56595), y = c(-150303.4661, 
-150303.4661, -150303.4661, -150303.4662)), .Names = c("x", "y"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
DF
         x         y
1 18.10000 -150303.5
2 18.16283 -150303.5
3 18.21251 -150303.5
4 18.56595 -150303.5

# Below are the assumed conditions: x > 18.2 and y <= -15:
length(subset(DF, x > 18.2 & y <= -15)) / nrow(DF)
[1] 0.5
```